# Sync with Sitecore - error - Exception Illegal characters in path

Tags: tds

I am working with a solution containing several TDS projects. All three can connect to my local server and pass the build test. However, I cannot Sync with Sitecore for the TDS project containing the templates because I'm getting an error when attempting to Sync with Sitecore:

```
Exception Illegal characters in path. (ArgumentException):
   at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)
   at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.Utils.SitecoreIconCache.GetIconPathForItem(SitecoreProjectNode project, SitecoreItemNode item, Boolean onlyUseCache)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.Controls.SitecoreSyncTreeNode..ctor(SitecoreItemNode sitecoreItemNode)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.Controls.SyncWithSitecore.AddItemToSync(SitecoreItemNode sitecoreItemNode)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.ToolWindows.SyncWithSitecoreToolWindow.SyncItemsWithSitecore(SitecoreProjectNode project, HierarchyNode node, TdsServiceSoapClient client)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.ToolWindows.SyncWithSitecoreToolWindow.SyncItemsWithSitecore(SitecoreProjectNode project, HierarchyNode node, TdsServiceSoapClient client)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.ToolWindows.SyncWithSitecoreToolWindow.SyncItemsWithSitecore(SitecoreProjectNode project, HierarchyNode node, TdsServiceSoapClient client)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.ToolWindows.SyncWithSitecoreToolWindow.SyncItemsWithSitecore(SitecoreProjectNode project, HierarchyNode node, TdsServiceSoapClient client)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.ToolWindows.SyncWithSitecoreToolWindow.SyncItemsWithSitecore(SitecoreProjectNode project, SitecoreItemNode syncRoot, Boolean sycnChildren)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreProjectPackage.ShowSitecoreSyncWindow(IEnumerable`1 projects, SitecoreItemNode selectedItem, Boolean syncChildren)
```

Because the error does not say what specific path is problematic, I am not sure how to troubleshoot the problem.

I am using Sitecore 9.2 and TDS 5.8.0.14

Comment: What is template name that you are trying to sync in TDS

Comment: I can't name any particular one - it's a massive project with possibly hundreds of templates.